# What option do I have if I get a kernel panic due to error in memory?

Tags: hardware, ram

I stumbled upon a kernel panic error trying to kill init.

I checked using Memtest and found errors in my memory i.e. Ram.

Now I don't want to lose my data. What should I do now? Thanks.

PS. Im not able to boot from live cd as well. So I cant provide any more relevant data. But I found that this is due to hardware problem but how should I proceed now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mem test showing errors tells you that you have a bad memory module, your data is safe in your hard disk and should not be affected.

Possible solutions to make your system boot again:

1. Remove one by one the memory modules in your computer and try booting again, replace if possible the bad memory module with a working one;

   - It should be easy enough to locate, remove and install modules in any computer. They are normally located near the CPU socket:

     [image]
   - Restore the memory modules that are good back to their original positions.
2. Make a backup of your disk and restore it in to a working computer, with minimal work you will be able to boot it up in to your working environment without issues.

Comment: I changed the memory module now it passed the memory test successfully. But Im still getting this error when trying to boot Ubuntu. But now Im able to boot from Ubuntu live cd.

Comment: Boot from the Ubuntu livecd and do a fsck to see if your data integrity is good. If it passes then try booting again, else copy your files and re-install, it is possible the that the bad memory module messed up your system.

Comment: I did `fsck` but it gave output `fsck from util-linux 2.20.1` . I tried to access the partition but it gave error `Unable to mount filesystem`  `mount: wrong fs type,bad option,bad superblock on /dev/sda1`

Comment: `Unable to mount filesystem mount: wrong fs type,bad option,bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`

Comment: If you are booting from the LiveCD you do not need to mount your disks to access it, just open nautilus and click on your partitions on the tree menu on the side panel.

Comment: Finally solved the problem using the command `fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sda1`. Thanks Bruno.